# Caracteres especiales en C

Tags: c

Al grano. Necesito imprimir este nombre en C con puros printf, y no puedo imprimir " \ " y algunos paréntesis tampoco, de hecho, en la linea 8 el paréntesis del printf no cierra, lo toma como parte de otro paréntesis que esta en la cadena.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf(" _    _               _                 _    _                _");
    printf("| |  | |            _| |_              | \  / |              (_)");
    printf("| |__| |  ___   ___|_   _| ___   _ __  |  \/  |");
    printf("| ____ | / _ \ / __\ | |  / _ \ | '__) | |\/| | / _' | / __\ | | / _' |/ __|");
    printf("| |  | |   __/  (__  | |   (_)  | |    | |  | || (_| |  (__  | || (_| |\__ \");
    printf("|_|  |_| \___| \___/ |_|  \___/ |_|    |_|  |_| \__'_| \___/ |_| \__'_ |___/");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El `\` es un caracter de escape. Con este accedes a caracteres especiales. Asi como por ejemplo `\n`, que es un salto de linea, `\t` que es un tab, etc. No existe un caracter de escape que sea `\`  (el `\` mas el espacio). Por eso te tira un error.

Lo que tienes que hacer es escapar el caracter. Lo escapas de la misma manera en la que escapas los demas caracteres, poniendo un `\` antes del mismo. Te queda asi: `\\`

De este modo puedes escapar caracteres especiales, por ejemplo, si quieres imprimir unas comillas, puedes ponerlas asi:

```
printf("\"Hola Mundo\"\n");
```

Y te imprime:

```
"Hola Mundo"
```

Entonces lo unico que tienes que hacer es escapar los caracteres especiales, y agregar los saltos de linea:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf(" _    _               _                 _    _                _\n");
    printf("| |  | |            _| |_              | \\  / |              (_)\n");
    printf("| |__| |  ___   ___|_   _| ___   _ __  |  \\/  |\n");
    printf("| ____ | / _ \\ / __\\ | |  / _ \\ | '__) | |\\/| | / _' | / __\\ | | / _' |/ __|\n");
    printf("| |  | |   __/  (__  | |   (_)  | |    | |  | || (_| |  (__  | || (_| |\\__ \\\n");
    printf("|_|  |_| \\___| \\___/ |_|  \\___/ |_|    |_|  |_| \\__'_| \\___/ |_| \\__'_ |___/\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Ya no se mira tan bonito, pero lo imprime de la manera correcta

**Una recomendacion:** El compilador te avisa que algo hiciste mal, y te dice que fue lo que hiciste mal. Te recomiendo que mires el error que te da, lo leas, buscalo en google, o si nos vas a contar de que no te funciona, minimo incluye el error. No siempre es algo tan trivial

Answer (score 1):

Hay que escapar todos los backslashes `\` porque son caracteres especiales (con otro backslash) y, de paso, hacer explícito el fin de línea.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf(" _    _               _                 _    _                _\n");
    printf("| |  | |            _| |_              | \\  / |              (_)\n");
    printf("| |__| |  ___   ___|_   _| ___   _ __  |  \\/  |\n");
    printf("| ____ | / _ \\ / __\\ | |  / _ \\ | '__) | |\\/| | / _' | / __\\ | | / _' |/ __|\n");
    printf("| |  | |   __/  (__  | |   (_)  | |    | |  | || (_| |  (__  | || (_| |\\__ \\\n");
    printf("|_|  |_| \\___| \\___/ |_|  \\___/ |_|    |_|  |_| \\__'_| \\___/ |_| \\__'_ |___/\n");

    return 0;
}
```